# ajax call success not binding in datatable

Tags: c#, json, ajax, datatables, asp.net-core-mvc

i have ajax call success to bind data to table but whin i want to apply datatable to my table it shows as the picture below and not binding data: [image: data in the datatable]

and here is my code

```
<script>

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Reports/Pendings/",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        cache: false,
        traditional: true,
        dataType: "json",
        processData: true,
        "xhrFields": {
            "withCredentials": true
        },
        success: function (data) {
            for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
                // Replaced key based access(.Key) by index access([1])
                var row = $('<tr><td>' + data[i][0] + '</td><td>' + data[i][1] + '</td><td>' + data[i][2] + '</td><td>' + data[i][3] + '</td><td>' + data[i][4] + '</td><td>' + data[i][5] + '</td><td>' + data[i][6] + '</td><td>' + data[i][7] + '</td></tr>');
                $('#table').append(row);
               

            }

            },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Error: ' + textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown);
        }
        });
  

</script>
<script>

    $('#table').DataTable();

</script>
```

Comment: Are you supposed to be sending some data in that post request? There is not much we can help with if your problem is server-side and you've only shown client-side

Comment: yes i have to and my data are fine just i want to bind them to datatables, they show fine in normal table tak a look at the first row.

Comment: You have not set any Post data on the request

Comment: my data are json data returened from an API check below link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67160234/json-data-in-table-display-as-undefined-in-asp-net-core/67161330#67161330

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax call has no `data` property on it so you can't possibly be submitting anything to the server in this request.

Your data should include values from form fields, etc.

```
    // Put your data here.
    let postData = { ... };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Reports/Pendings/",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        cache: false,
        traditional: true,
        dataType: "json",
        processData: true,
        data: postData, // Include your postData here.
        "xhrFields": {
            "withCredentials": true
        },
        success: function (data) {
            for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
                // Replaced key based access(.Key) by index access([1])
                var row = $('<tr><td>' + data[i][0] + '</td><td>' + data[i][1] + '</td><td>' + data[i][2] + '</td><td>' + data[i][3] + '</td><td>' + data[i][4] + '</td><td>' + data[i][5] + '</td><td>' + data[i][6] + '</td><td>' + data[i][7] + '</td></tr>');
                $('#table').append(row);
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Error: ' + textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

Comment: dear my data are returened from an API check this link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67160234/json-data-in-table-display-as-undefined-in-asp-net-core/67161330#67161330

Comment: my problem is just that to be fetched to the datatable not the normal table.

Comment: You will still need to move it from the ajax call to the server before you can put it in your database. So in the code I posted, replace `postData` with whatever you're getting from the api

Answer (score 0):

You need to init the datatable in the ajax success callback function, since ajax is default asynchronous.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Reports/Pendings/",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    cache: false,
    traditional: true,
    dataType: "json",
    processData: true,
    success: function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var row = $('<tr><td>' + data[i][0] + '</td><td>' + data[i][1] + '</td><td>' + data[i][2] + '</td><td>' + data[i][3] + '</td><td>' + data[i][4] + '</td><td>' + data[i][5] + '</td><td>' + data[i][6] + '</td><td>' + data[i][7] + '</td></tr>');

            $('#myTable').append(row);
        }

        $("#myTable").dataTable();            //init here
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('Error: ' + textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

CDN:

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
```

Comment: it gives error as below
TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
    at Object.success

Comment: Did you add the `jquery.dataTables.min.js reference`